# How can I access UserManager and RoleManager from a Console App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I access `UserManager` and/or `RoleManger` in a non-hosted, [asp.net-5](/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) Console Application package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        // do whatever
    }

    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

    public Program(IApplicationEnvironment env, IServiceManifest serviceManifest)
    {
        Configuration =
            new ConfigurationBuilder(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("config.json") // add the file to your project
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);
        serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];

        // Register EntityFramework 7
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        // Register UserManager & RoleManager
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // UserManager & RoleManager require logging and HttpContext dependencies
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }
}
```

**config.json**

```
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\ProjectsV12;Database=my-database-name;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which packages are required for this?